# ubuntu lock screen not changing background

Tags: gnome, themes, lock-screen

Before you mark this as duplicate, I've tried everything out there.
I've been fiddling with gnome tweaks and added a theme by following this tutorial, https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/make-ubuntu-look-like-mac-5-steps
I tried changing the, I followed this tutorial to change the background, https://vitux.com/how-to-change-login-lock-screen-background-in-ubuntu/. In a gist, it says to change this file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` which I did. When I lock my screen by pressing <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> it shows up but when I go restart my pc it never shows up. My theme is stored in a `.themes` folder in my home folder. I use the basic gdm3 which can installed when installing ubuntu 18.04. It is quite annoying that it doesn't persist.

Comment: Did you try changing the Lock Screen Background instead of changing it through the Terminal?

Comment: what do you mean I don't understand

Comment: Could you tell me about the version of Ubuntu?

Comment: i use ubuntu 18.04 with gdm3

Comment: sadly this is one of the few changes which do require a reboot ... if a reboot springs your new background into action please update your question as such

Comment: I have rebooted the system multiple times

Comment: what is the output of `sudo update-alternatives -- config gdm3.css`

Comment: when I put it into the terminal I get this `There is only one alternative in link group gdm3.css (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css): /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
Nothing to configure.
`

Comment: If I change the css in both files it works only when I press `⊞ Win` +`L` not if I reboot, I want it to work even if I reboot